# How do I store multiline text in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
public static String ReplaceNewLines(String source, bool allowNewLines)
{
     if (allowNewLines)
          source = source.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
     else
          source = source.Replace("\r\n", " ");
     return source;
}

protected void btnSubmit_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     String txtInput = ReplaceNewLines(txtQuestion.Text, true);
     String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          // Sql Commands here...
     } 
}
```

When the button above is clicked, data is inserted into the database like this:

```
Test line one. <br /> test line two.
```

What I want is it to look like this:

```
Test line one.<br />Test line two.
```

How do I set up my code behind so the `<br />` does not show up in the SQL query and creates another line in my page when I call it from the database?

Comment: Well... don't call `ReplaceNewLines` before saving the text to the database, but call if when you retrieve text from the database instead.

Comment: Where are you viewing it?

Comment: is it `<br />` or `< br />` these 2 are not the same.. so why not do a joined replace meaning chain the Replace function to look for both scenarios...

Comment: I had to use < br / > in my question because it wasn't formatting how i wanted it.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski So how does that work if I am calling that text?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: The formatting isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
source = source.Replace("\r\n", "" + ((char)13).ToString() + (char)10).ToString();
```

Those are the carriage return and line feed characters.

Comment: This generates invalid arguments.

Comment: Sorry... have to convert the char to strings.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I believe this is a step in the right direction, when I debug it the text shows up as **"Line one.\r\n Line two."**

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the correct information. The break (`<br/>`) will give you a new line if you show the result in a browser for example who can make an interpretation of the hmtl.

Comment: It would do that however and I forgot to mention I'm using a gridview to display the information.  It displays the <br> in the text.

Comment: Try decoding the content

Answer (score 0):

Add "carriage return" and "line feed" characters, see the example

SELECT 'THIS IS A COMMENT LINE 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'THIS IS LINE 2'

### Output

THIS IS A COMMENT LINE 1
THIS IS LINE 2